# Can't change default application for .3gp files

Tags: 20.04, nautilus, video, file-association

I manually changed `/etc/gnome/defaults.list` file to set a different application than Totem for playing video files. It is actually a specific wrapper script around Totem that sets a few things before playing the video, and I created a file `/usr/share/applications/auto-totem.desktop` for it. All `video/...=` lines in this file specify my `auto-totem.desktop` file, including `video/3gpp`.

However, this doesn't work for this file type (works for all other video files) - these files open in original Totem (without my wrapper script), moreover, I cannot change the default application using "Preferences" menu. Totem is shown as default application for opening these files and when I select another application and click "Set as default", it has no effect - the default reverts to Totem.

What is strange, when I set a default application in "Preferences", the correct line `video/3gpp=auto-totem.desktop` **is** actually written to the file `~/.config/mimeapps.list`. Moreover, `xdg-mime query default video/3gpp` shows correctly the `auto-totem.desktop` file for my application and `mimeopen file.3gp` correctly opens the file in my application. Only Nautilus behaves strangely and forces opening these files in Totem. I thought that maybe something is cached for the session so I logged out & logged back in, but this did not help.

This is not specific to my application, when I tried to set another application as default for `video/3gpp` files (like mpv or vlc), the same happens - I cannot set anything other than Totem.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Answering to myself - this is not a full answer, because I don't know what actually happened and why, but deleting my `~/.config/mimeapps.list` file helped. That is, after deleting the file the default application for `video/3gpp` files was still Totem (despite entry in `/etc/gnome/defaults.list`) - that is probably some bug? - but at least I was able to change it using "Preferences" menu. Of course I had to recreate a few associations that were in my `~/.config/mimeapps.list` file that I made previously.